# How to encode OpenCV image matrix to base64 in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv, matrix

I currently have a program running that sends an OpenCV to my Node server by sending the matrix values along with the number of rows and columns. I want to base64 encode this image on the Node server so I can view the image on the front end. I tried doing a .toString('base64') on the matrices values but this didnt work. My question is related to this question [OpenCV cv::Mat to std::ifstream for base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003981/opencv-cvmat-to-stdifstream-for-base64-encoding) but instead of doing this in C++ Id like to do it on Node.

 Heres what the matrices values look like when comma separated.
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do Base64 encoding in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182315/how-to-do-base64-encoding-in-node-js)

Comment: As mentioned I attempted this method, Im not sure the mat image can be directly encoded to base64

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
const outBase64 =  cv.imencode('.jpg', outputImage).toString('base64');
const output = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + outBase64;
return output;
```

Obviously depending on your image format you might need to change the encoding.