# Libcurl C++ Convert std::string to cv::Mat object

Tags: c++, json, opencv, curl

I have a C++ implementation that uses Libcurl to pull down a JSON object that contains an image in a byte[ ]. I then need to convert this into a Mat object so that I can process it using openCV. The string I extract the JSON Value into prints out what appears to be a valid byte array. Same for printing the vector. Every method I have tried to convert this into a Mat object results int the following error. Any help would be appreciated.

Error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file 
/Users/Misanthropic/opencv-3.0.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 271
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: 
/Users/Misanthropic/opencv-3.0.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:271: error: 
(-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

Code:

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
const cv::_InputArray data;
std::string readBuffer;

char *url = "http://ezquote-server.herokuapp.com/requestImageFile";
curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
readBuffer.clear();
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

//printf("%s\n\n", readBuffer.c_str());
printf("Image retrieved.\n");
Json::Value values;
Json::Reader reader;
reader.parse(readBuffer, values);

Json::Value imageArray = values.get("userUploadedImage","default    
value");
Json::Value idNumber = values.get("id","default value");
Json::FastWriter fastWriter;
std::string output = fastWriter.write(imageArray);

//cout << output << endl;

std::vector<byte> vectordata(output.begin(), output.end());

//for (auto i = vectordata.begin(); i != vectordata.end(); ++i)
//std::cout << *i;

cv::Mat data_mat(vectordata,true);
cv::Mat  image(cv::imdecode(data_mat, 1));
std::cout<<"Height: " << image.rows <<" Width: "<<image.cols<<endl;

cv::namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
cv::imshow( "Display Image",image);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

Output of String and Vector:

```
"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"
```

Comment: Clearly this is assertion failure, the condition `size.width>0 && size.height>0` failed. Either image size or height or both are less than 0. Check `vectordata` contents.

Comment: Vector contents appear to be fine when I print it out. I get what the error message is saying, just not sure why the Mat objects width and height are 0.

Comment: There is a problem while constructing `cv::Mat` object from `vectordata`.

Comment: That is what I figured but I don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: Can you post the content of `output` string?

Comment: your string is encode base64. Try using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32270463/5008845) solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the string was base64 encoded. All credit to Miki in the comments above for pointing me to an appropriate solution. Since I cannot vote a comment as the answer I am writing this to ensure people see the solution. The link below will provide the appropriate string encoding conversion.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32270463/5008845)