# stringstream to base64 encode and send it to the server ios

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv

Using open cv I am getting descriptors in `cv::Mat` format. Converting
`cv::Mat` to `stringstream` is happening with this method:

```
/// Serialize a cv::Mat to a stringstream
stringstream serialize(Mat input)
{
    // We will need to also serialize the width, height, type and size of the matrix
    int width = input.cols;
    int height = input.rows;
    int type = input.type();
    size_t size = input.total() * input.elemSize();

    // Initialize a stringstream and write the data
    stringstream ss;
    ss.write((char*)(&width), sizeof(int));
    ss.write((char*)(&height), sizeof(int));
    ss.write((char*)(&type), sizeof(int));
    ss.write((char*)(&size), sizeof(size_t));

    // Write the whole image data
    ss.write((char*)input.data, size);

    return ss;
}
```

Now i want to convert this `stringstream` into base64 encoded. How to
make it possible in direct method.

Comment: I usually use [this piece of code](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html) to perform base64 coding/encoding. But can't you just send the YAML/XML?

Comment: Also, in your serialization you should take care of the case when image is not continuous. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32357875/5008845) for reference, at `matwrite` method

Comment: But i referred the post they mentioned base 64 is best option.. thats why am converting.. which one is best.. xml or yaml or base64???

Comment: i just want to send the descriptors(cv::Mat format) to webserver.. kindly suggest.. am using opencv 3.0

Comment: Hi i just want to convert stringstream format to base64 encode.. but you mention from string to base64 conversion..

Comment: I don't know enough about webservers or networks to recommend base64 or YAML/XML. Probably first is more compact, second easier. However, improve your `serialize` function as in the link, and encode to base64 with the code of the first link. That's it

Comment: `ss.str()` returns ta string

Comment: Hi i dont want to convert it into string.. i just want this stringstream to be converted directly to the base64 encode.. do you know any base64 lib to convert it.. i have one link but i cant connect it to the project.. Here is the link for the library.. http://libb64.sourceforge.net/... Got this link from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003981/opencv-cvmat-to-stdifstream-for-base64-encoding

Comment: Since that lib is in ANSI C, then it's unlikely that it works directly on `stringstream`. What's the matter to get the string from the stringstream?

Comment: So you are suggesting that convert mat to string and string to base64 to send data to the webserver.. am i right???   so here is a method to convert mat to string... // cvmat to nsstring..

- (NSString*) NSStringFromCvMat:(cv::Mat)mat
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << mat;
    return [NSString stringWithCString:ss.str().c_str() encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}

Comment: and from string to base64 conversion have to use your link http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html \

Comment: No, I'm suggesting to serialize the matrix with stringstream and encode the string you get from the stringstream. You can use that link for decoding, or whatever you prefer.

Comment: // cvmat to nsstring.. - (NSString*) NSStringFromCvMat:(cv::Mat)mat { std::stringstream ss; ss << mat; return [NSString stringWithCString:ss.str().c_str() encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; }  Is this way right??? getting nsstring from cvmat.. then encode the string..

Comment: use your `serialize` function to serialize to stringstream

Comment: Don't know objectiveC, but something like: `std::string s = serialize(mat).str(); std::string encoded = encode_base64(s);` where `encode_base64` is your encoding function (as in the link, for example)

Comment: Ya that is done.. Here it is..    std::stringstream ss;
    
    ss = serialize(descriptors1);    next what i have to do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode the `string` obtained by the `stringstream` like:

```
Mat m;
...
std::string s = serialize(m).str();
std::string encoded = base64_encode(s.c_str());
// send "encoded" to server
```

The code for `base64_encode` can be found, for example, [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html).

Comment: - (void) frameCaptured:(cv::Mat) frame{

    cv::Mat greyMat;
    
    
    cv::cvtColor(frame, greyMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    
  //  UIImage *finaleImg = [self UIImageFromCVMat:greyMat];
    
    orb -> detect(greyMat, keypoints1);
    
    orb -> compute(greyMat, keypoints1, descriptors1);
    
    drawKeypoints(greyMat, keypoints1, outImage);
std::string s = serialize(descriptors1).str(); std::string encoded = base64_encode(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(s.c_str()), s.length());
    

    NSLog(@"%s",encoded.c_str());
}

Comment: Here am getting data from camera and creating descriptors in mat format.. now am serializing the mat format and encoded into base64 format..

Comment: Is this right?? Then how can i send it through the socket...??

Comment: I can't test your code. You should know if it works ok or not. The question is about getting base64 encoding, and this is what my answer is about. Sockets and network related stuff should go in another question.

Comment: For serialization am using this method...// Serialize a cv::Mat to a stringstream

Comment: std::stringstream serialize(cv::Mat input)
{// We will need to also serialize the width, height, type and size of the matrix
    int width = input.cols;
    int height = input.rows;
    int type = input.type();
   size_t size = input.total() * input.elemSize();
//    // Initialize a stringstream and write the data
   std::stringstream ss;
    ss.write((char*)(&width), sizeof(int));
    ss.write((char*)(&height), sizeof(int));
    ss.write((char*)(&type), sizeof(int));
    ss.write((char*)(&size), sizeof(size_t));
  
    ss.write((char*)input.data, size);
    return ss;
}